# How to give primary key to java variable in Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I tried @Id to particular field but in database it is not affecting.

```
@Id
private String id;
```

Comment: did you add @Entity at the class level too?

Comment: yes I have added a @Entity at the class level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before trying make sure there is no any other primary key to your d_table

try this one

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_tbl")
public class User {

   public User() {}

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "user_email")
   private String email;
}
```